# HTML list with space

Tags: html, css

I have to two list side by side. In one list I want to have some space between two `li` (an empty `li`).

For example I want somthing like this

```
A    B
A    B
A    
A    B
```

I just put an empty `li` and it works.
But I want to remove the bullet so in the css I add `list-style-type: none;` but this remove the space and I get something like this :

```
A    B
A    B
A    B
A
```

How can I do?

Comment: You want to have two side by side lists and it matters that particular items in one list line up with particular items in the other? Are you sure you don't have tabular data?

Comment: How about some actual HTML and CSS? Maybe even a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li
{
    list-style-type: none; // Removes bullet  
    min-height: 12px; // Font size you're using
    padding: 1px; // Add extra padding or margin if needed
}
```

or a dirty method using an empty spacer (not recommended)

```
list-style-image:url('spacer.gif');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `min-height:1em` to the style for the li.

Edit: wait, 1em only works if the line-height is 100%. Make sure the min height is the same as the calculated line height (for example, by setting the line-height to 100%).